# Improve performance of `compute_optimal_weights` function in Python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there a faster way to write "compute_optimal_weights" function in Python. I run it hundreds of millions of times, so any speed increase would help. The arguments of the function are different each time I run it.

```
c1 = 0.25
c2 = 0.67

def compute_optimal_weights(input_prices):
    input_weights_optimal = {}
    for i in input_prices:
        price = input_prices[i]
        input_weights_optimal[i] = c2 / sum([(price/n) ** c1 for n in input_prices.values()])
    return input_weights_optimal

input_sellers_ID = range(10)
input_prices = {}
for i in input_sellers_ID:
    input_prices[i] = random.uniform(0,1)


t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(1000000):
    compute_optimal_weights(input_prices)
t1 = time.time()
print "old time", (t1 - t0)
```

The number of elements in list and dictionary vary, but on average there are about 10 elements. They keys in input_prices are the same across all calls but the values change, so the same key will have different values over different runs.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the code in a profiler. Also look at the feasibility of caching or memoizing values that may unnecessarily be recalculated many times. One other thing is that perhaps `itertools.product` may present an opportunity to avoid the double for loop and push more of the processing out of the interpreter and into the underlying c code.

Comment: What versions of python are available to you? Are you limited to 2.x (as `xrange` would suggest)?

Comment: I am using 2.7, but I can change to 3.x if there is a faster way to do this...

Comment: How long are your lists, and how many entries in your dictionary? It would be helpful to know a little about how often they change too and by how many entries. Could you edit your question to include some example data? And do the keys in `input_prices` always refer to the same value across multiple calls? For example, whenever the key `1` is present does it always refer to the value `0.5`, or can that association change?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have added the information you asked for in the question. I have also replaced the earlier function with a somewhat faster function.

Comment: Normally when doing computations and you need speedup you take numpy or numba. I tried that and it didn't really worked out, I think because there are so few numbers but you call the function often. Functioncalls in python are quite costly, is it possible to group some of the function calls together and then calculate multiple values in one call? Or do you get the values only one after the other?

Comment: @user58925 Thank you for updating your post with that information. I have posted my solution below, and reduced the run time of the program by ~80% for your stated average input size. Let me know if you have any questions about the code or the math behind it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little bit of math, you can calculate part of your `sum_price_ratio_scaled` as a constant earlier in the loop and speed up your program by **~80%** (for the average input size of 10).

---

### Optimized Implementation (Python 3):

```
def compute_optimal_weights(ids, prices):
    scaled_sum = 0
    for i in ids:
        scaled_sum += prices[i] ** -0.25
    result = {}
    for i in ids:
        result[i] = 0.67 * (prices[i] ** -0.25) / scaled_sum
    return result
```

**Edit, in response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43514220/7256039):** While using `numpy` will prove more performant with massive data sets, given that *"on average there are about 10 elements"* in your `input_sellers_ID` list, I doubt that this approach is worth its own weight for your particular application.

Although it might be tempting to leverage the terseness of generator expressions and dictionary comprehensions, I noticed when running on my machine that the best performance was obtained by using regular `for-in` loops and avoiding function calls like `sum(...)`. For the sake of completeness, though, here is what the above implementation would look like in a more 'pythonic' style:

```
def compute_optimal_weights(ids, prices):
    scaled_sum = sum(prices[i] ** -0.25 for i in ids)
    return {i: 0.67 * (prices[i] ** -0.25) / scaled_sum for i in ids}
```

---

### Reasoning / Math:

Based on your posted algorithm, you are trying to create a dictionary with values represented by the function `f(i)` below, where `i` is one of the elements in your `input_sellers_ID` list.

When you initially write out the formula for `f(i)`, it appears as though `prices[i]` must be recalculated for every step of the summation process, which is costly. Simplifying the expression using the rules of exponents, however, you can see that the simplest summation needed to determine `f(i)` is actually *independent* of `i` (only the index value of `j` is ever used), meaning that that term is a constant and can be calculated outside of the loop which sets the dictionary values.

[image]

Note that above I refer to `input_prices` as `prices` and `input_sellers_ID` as `ids`.

---

### Performance Profile (~80% speed improvement on my machine, size 10):

```
import time
import random

def compute_optimal_weights(ids, prices):
    scaled_sum = 0
    for i in ids:
        scaled_sum += prices[i] ** -0.25
    result = {}
    for i in ids:
        result[i] = 0.67 * (prices[i] ** -0.25) / scaled_sum
    return result

def compute_optimal_weights_old(input_sellers_ID, input_prices):
    input_weights_optimal = {}
    for i in input_sellers_ID:
        sum_price_ratio_scaled = 0
        for j in input_sellers_ID:
            price_ratio = input_prices[i] / input_prices[j]
            scaled_price_ratio = price_ratio ** c1
            sum_price_ratio_scaled += scaled_price_ratio
        input_weights_optimal[i] = c2 / sum_price_ratio_scaled
    return input_weights_optimal


c1 = 0.25
c2 = 0.67
input_sellers_ID = range(10)
input_prices = {i: random.uniform(0,1) for i in input_sellers_ID}

start = time.clock()
for _ in range(1000000):
    compute_optimal_weights_old(input_sellers_ID, input_prices) and None

old_time = time.clock() - start

start = time.clock()
for _ in range(1000000):
    compute_optimal_weights(input_sellers_ID, input_prices) and None

new_time = time.clock() - start

print('Old:', compute_optimal_weights_old(input_sellers_ID, input_prices))
print('New:', compute_optimal_weights(input_sellers_ID, input_prices))
print('New algorithm is {:.2%} faster.'.format(1 - new_time / old_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe we could speed-up the function by factoring the loop. Let `a = price`, `b = n` and `c = c1`, if my maths are not wrong (e.g. `(5/6)**3 == 5**3 / 6**3`:

```
(5./6.)**2 + (5./4.)**2
== 
5**2 / 6.**2 + 5**2 / 4.**2
== 
5**2 * (1/6.**2 + 1/4.**2)
```

With variables:

```
sum( (a / b) ** c for each b)
==
sum( a**c * (1/b) ** c for each b)
==
a**c * sum((1./b)**c for each b)
```

The second term is constant and can be taken out. Which leaves:

## Faster implementation - Raw Python

Using generators and dict-comprehension:

```
def compute_optimal_weights(input_prices):
    sconst = sum(1/w**c1 for w in input_prices.values())
    return {k: c2 / (v**c1 * sconst) for k, v in input_prices.items()}
```

NOTE: if you are using Python2 replace `.values()` and `.items()` with `.itervalues()` and `.iteritems()` for extra speedup (few ms with large lists).

---

## Even Faster - Numpy

Additionally, if you don't care that much about the dictionary and just want the values, you could speed it up using numpy (for large inputs `>100`):

```
def compute_optimal_weights_np(input_prices):
    data = np.asarray(input_prices.values()) ** c1
    return c2 / (data * np.sum(1./data))
```

---

Few timings for different input size:

- `N = 10` inputs:

  ```
  MINE:  100000 loops, best of 3: 6.02 µs per loop
  NUMPY: 100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop
  YOURS: 10000 loops, best of 3: 23.8 µs per loop
  ```
- `N = 100` inputs:

  ```
  MINE:  10000 loops, best of 3: 49.1 µs per loop
  NUMPY: 10000 loops, best of 3: 22.6 µs per loop
  YOURS: 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
  ```
- `N = 1000` inputs:

  ```
  MINE:  1000 loops, best of 3: 458 µs per loop
  NUMPY: 10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop
  YOURS: 10 loops, best of 3: 173 ms per loop
  ```
- `N = 100000` inputs:

  ```
  MINE:  10 loops, best of 3: 54.2 ms per loop
  NUMPY: 100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
  YOURS: didn't finish in a couple of minutes
  ```

Both options here are considerably faster than the one presented in the question. The benefit of using `numpy` if you can give consistent input (in the form of array instead of a dictionary) becomes apparent when the size grows: